# How to Find and Update Multiple Array Elements in mongodb

Tags: arrays, mongodb, mongodb-query

```
> db.Dashboards.find({user:{$regex:"adams"}}).pretty();
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("123"),
    "user" : "adam.adams",
    "widgets" : [
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("124"),
            "column" : 1,
            "configMap" : {
                "coleg" : "bas.baser,cer.ceras,tom.tomsa"
            },
        }
    ]
}
```

I have a Mongo database that keeps records like the one above, unfortunately I need to find all users who have "cer.ceras" in the "coleg" field and then replace this with "per.peras"

I try with

```
db.Dashboards.find({widgets:{"$elemMatch":{configMap:{"$elemMatch":{coleg:/.*ceras.*/}}}}}}).pretty();
```

But I'm not finding anything for me

Comment: By "replace", do you mean update the documents in the database?

Comment: yes but only change  "cer.ceras" to "per.peras"

Comment: Well, to get you started, here's a [mongoplayground.net example](https://mongoplayground.net/p/M-qEC9C35KW) that will find the documents that need to be changed.  Note that the regex I used there, `"cer\\.ceras"`, may be be slightly different for you depending on the escaping rules of your strings.  I needed to have two backslashes so that just one would be in the regex string to escape the `.`.  `.` needs to be escaped so it's not interpreted in the regex as "any single character match" - you actually want to match a `.`.  Of course your `update` will need a bit more, can you try it?

Comment: It works! Thanks to this, I can see all the users I wanted

Answer (score 0):

*This may a bit complex.*

**Filter**:

The criteria should work with `$regex` to find the occurrence of the text.

**Update**:

Require the update with aggregation pipeline.

1. `$set` - Set `widgets` field.

   1.1. `$map` - Iterate the element in the `widgets` array and return a new array.

   1.1.1. `$mergeObjects` - Merge current iterate document with the result of *1.1.1.1*.

   1.1.1.1. A document with `configMap` array. With `$mergeObjects` to merge current iterate `configMap` document with the result *1.1.1.1.1*.

   1.1.1.1.1. A document with `coleg` field. With `$replaceAll` to replace all matching text "cer.ceras" to "per.peras".

**Update Options**

`{ multi: true }` aims to update multiple documents.

```
db.collection.update({
  widgets: {
    $elemMatch: {
      "configMap.coleg": {
        $regex: "cer\\.ceras"
      }
    }
  }
},
[
  {
    $set: {
      widgets: {
        $map: {
          input: "$widgets",
          in: {
            $mergeObjects: [
              "$$this",
              {
                configMap: {
                  $mergeObjects: [
                    "$$this.configMap",
                    {
                      coleg: {
                        $replaceAll: {
                          input: "$$this.configMap.coleg",
                          find: "cer.ceras",
                          replacement: "per.peras"
                        }
                      }
                    }
                  ]
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
],
{
  multi: true
})
```

[Demo @ Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/SfWzR0ekuUQ)

Comment: [Here it is](https://mongoplayground.net/p/1C29vBUOVw0 "Link to mongoplayground.net -->") working on an expanded `"widgets"` array.